# Mobile Apps remember login without saving password

Tags: android, ios, codeigniter

What strategy should I follow if I need to remember login in a mobile client if the company policy restricts me from storing password in the mobile client.

Answer (score 1):

Time limited token.
You have multiple options:
1. After successful login create time limited token on server and send it to client. Don't forget to generate new token often enough, to prevent it's expiration (ideally on every request)
2. After successful login share secret key, used to generate token between client and server (ideally newly generated secret). Then you can use this secret on client to generate token when needed.

In any case, every client request should contain token + some signature for ensuring that request hasn't change by third party.

Answer (score 0):

You can save auth token when user log into app. Then use this token with your requests to backend, if you get 401 http error (not authorized) this means your token is invalid or expired and you should logout user.

Answer (score 0):

You can store user_id and other user data in sharedPrefrences or database when the user logs in and clear data when the user logs out.

When the app starts you can check if data is already stored for that user then redirect to the main screen otherwise redirect to the login screen.